# Is it possible to restore a database in a mirroring configuration?

Tags: sql-server-2014, restore, mirroring

Or will I have to break the mirror, restore the database, then rebuild the mirror?

We're in the process of upgrading our SharePoint servers.  We already have two new  servers in place and they are currently mirrored.  If possible, I'd like to leave the servers in a mirrored state to save time during our maintenance window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database Mirroring must be removed to perform the restore. Break the mirror, do the restore and then setup mirroring again.

Comment: That is what i thought, Tara, thank you!  For some reason, I guess, I thought it would be possible this day and age.